# Loading player on top of map array

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

```
//getting canvas element and setting context
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

//setting canvas hight & width
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 608;
canvas.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
canvas.style.height = canvas.height + "px";

//Y
//|
//|
//. _ _ X
//
// X Y W H

//map array
var map = [
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1],
    [1,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1],
    [1,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1],
    [1,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1],
    [1,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1],
    [1,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1],
    [1,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1],
    [1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,1],
    [1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,1],
    [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,2,1],
    [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,2,1],
    [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,2,1],
    [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,2,1],
    [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,2,1],
    [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,2,1],
    [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,2,1],
    [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
];

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var imgSize = 32;

//images
var tiles = new Image();
var player = new Image();

//image source
tiles.src = "images/tileMap.png";

function init() {
    drawMap();
    drawPlayer();
}

function drawMap() {
    for (j = 0; j <= map.length; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < map[1].length; i++) {
            if (map[j][i] == 1) {
                context.drawImage(tiles,0,0,imgSize,imgSize,x,y,imgSize,imgSize);
            } else if (map[j][i] == 2) {
                context.drawImage(tiles,imgSize,0,imgSize,imgSize,x,y,imgSize,imgSize);
            } else if (map[j][i] == 3) {
                context.drawImage(tiles,imgSize*2,0,imgSize,imgSize,x,y,imgSize,imgSize);
            }
            x = x + imgSize;
        }
        x = 0;
        y = y + imgSize;
    }
}

function drawPlayer() {
    context.drawImage(tiles,imgSize*3,0,imgSize,imgSize,0,0,imgSize,imgSize);
}
```

Hello! I have an issue loading the player on top of the map array here and wondered if anyone could point out what I was doing wrong, thanks!

Also I have an error in the console "uncaught typeError: cannot read property'0' of undefined".

Also, something weird happens when I load the player before the map it works. I remove the tile where the play is and it appears. but when i load the player after the map it doesn't appear. im guessing its to do with the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "uncaught typeError" appear because you do this :

```
for (j = 0; j <= map.length; j++) {
map[j][i]...
}
```

If your map contain 3 element. You can access to each element with map[0], map[1] and map[2], but map[3] wiil return undefined.
In your loop, with my exemple, j goes from 0 to 3 and try to access to map[3]. map[3] return undefined, so you can't access to the property [i] of undefined.

You must write `for (j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {`